# Benders Decomposition cuts for MILP problem with further separable subproblems

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, benders-decomposition, decomposition

I am solving an OR scheduling problem where I assign the patient to (day,OR) tuple in Master Problem. Once the assignment is made, a subproblem can be solved for each (day,OR) tuple **independently** where patients are assigned to a time slot t. A cost of overtime is incurred if OR is occupied beyond a certain time slot.

It is ensured in the master problem that the assignment to each OR,day tuple is feasible. Thus, the subproblems are always feasible.

The benders cut added is of the form

[image]

Using this form, I add a cut for each (day,OR) tuple, if $$\phi(x^*)_{dk} > \sigma^*_{dk}$$ This cut essentially ensures that the solution is not repeated or the solution that is found is at least >= M (Lower Bound).

The cuts added from the relaxation of SP are valid for the original problem. However, is that the case when you further separate the problem as I have done before? Can I add the cuts from LP relaxation for each (OR,day) tuple?

I ask this question because I obtain the solution only when I have integer cuts of the form above, however, the lower bound is violated when I include the cuts from SP relaxation. Under what condition the cuts from LP relaxation are valid?

Comment: Are you asking about adding both the "no good" cuts in the image and the cuts from the LP dual, or are you asking about using the LP cuts instead of the "no good" cuts?

Comment: I want to use both the cuts however using cuts from LP dual in addition to no-good cuts resulted in the solution higher than optimal solution for the problem. It means that cuts from LP dual are removing integer feasible solutions.

Referring to the book "50 years of integer programming", the cuts added from LP relaxation of subproblems should also be valid. But could the case be different if I further decompose the problem by (day,OR) tuple? Could this be case that the cuts generated from individual problems are not valid anymore?

Comment: You'll have to write out a subproblem and the cut you are generating from it for this to be answered.

Comment: $$ \min c^u U  + c^o O + \sum_{t \in T,i \in N_{dk}} \lambda_{it} X_{it}$$
$$t * Z_{it} - O \leq S  \quad \forall  t \in T ,i \in N_{dk}$$
$$s - \sum_{i \in N_{dk}} \sum_{t = 1}^{S} Z_{it}   \leq U$$
$$\sum_{t' =  t}^{t+l_i-1} Z_{it'} \geq l_i * X_{it} \quad  \forall i \in N_{dk}, 1 \leq t \leq T-l_i+1$$
$$\sum_{t \in T} Z_{it} = l_i \quad \forall i \in N_{dk}$$
$$\sum_{i \in N_{dk}} Z_{it} \leq 1 \quad \forall t \in T$$
$$\sum_{t \in T} X_{it} = 1 \quad \forall i \in N_{dk}$$
$$\sum_{t = T-l_i+1}^{T} X_{it} = 0 \quad \forall i \in N_{dk}$$
$$O,U \geq 0, X,Z_{it} \in \{0,1\}$$

Comment: @prubin I missed a constraint above
constraint 8  = $$Z_{it} \geq X_{it} \quad \forall i \in N_{dk}, t \in T$$

I am generating cuts for above problem by using .Pi attribute from each constraint, where my cut is written as 

$$ \sigma_{dk} \geq \sum_{t \in T, i \in N_{dk}} S*{\Pi^1}_{it} + S {\Pi^2} + 0 \Pi^3 + \sum_{i \in N_{dk}} l_i {\Pi^4}_i +  \sum_{t \in T} 1  {\Pi^5}_{it} + \sum_{i \in N_{dk}} 1 {\Pi^6}_{i} + 0 \Pi^7 + 0  \Pi^8 $$

$X_{it}$: Binary- surgery i starts in time slot t
$Z_{it}$: Binary- surgery i occupies time slot t
$O$: Overtime
$U$: Idletime
$S$: SessionLength

Comment: These cuts are added in addition to the cuts I described above and discussed by @RobPratt below

Comment: Are the $\ell_i$ values of master problem variables being passed into the subproblem?

Comment: No. The variable that I have from master problem is $X_{idk}$ that decides surgery assignment to (day,OR). In above formulation that variable is missing. I was looking for guidance in the same. For example constraint 3 should have $l_i * X_{it}*X_{idk}$ where $X_{idk}$ is a parameter. But since the subproblems are separable, I was not sure how to include that variable as in constraint 3 I only used $i \in N_{dk}$ where  $N_{dk}$ is a set of surgeries assigned to a (day d,OR K).

I understand that this is incorrect formulation. How do I correct it?

Comment: If you want to use Benders, the master problem variables cannot multiply subproblem variables. So you might need to rewrite the third constraint as a "big M" type constraint.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your Benders master problem is to minimize $\sigma = \sum_{d,k} \sigma_{d,k}$, where your independent subproblems are indexed by $(d,k)$.
For each fixed master solution $x^*$, let $\phi(x^*)_{d,k}$ be the optimal objective value (or any lower bound, perhaps obtained from the LP relaxation) of subproblem $(d,k)$, and let $M$ be a valid lower bound on $\sigma_{d,k}$.  Then the following constraint ("combinatorial Benders optimality cut") is valid:
$$\sigma_{d,k} \ge \phi(x^*)_{d,k} - (\phi(x^*)_{d,k} - M) \left(\sum_{j: x_j^* = 0} x_j + \sum_{j: x_j^* = 1} (1-x_j)\right) \tag1$$
This (big-M) constraint enforces the logical implication $x=x^* \implies \sigma_{d,k} \ge \phi(x^*)_{d,k}$.

But this cut can be very weak.  If every subset of the support of $x^*$ yields $\sigma_{d,k} \ge \phi(x^*)_{d,k}$, you can strengthen as follows:
$$\sigma_{d,k} \ge \phi(x^*)_{d,k} - (\phi(x^*)_{d,k} - M) \sum_{j: x_j^* = 0} x_j \tag2$$

Similarly, if every superset of the support of $x^*$ yields $\sigma_{d,k} \ge \phi(x^*)_{d,k}$, you can strengthen as follows:
$$\sigma_{d,k} \ge \phi(x^*)_{d,k} - (\phi(x^*)_{d,k} - M) \sum_{j: x_j^* = 1} (1-x_j) \tag3$$

Comment: Thank you for elaborating the my question here in perfect way for everyone to understand. The objective function is $ min Z = \sum_{dk}  \sigma_{dk} + C^fQ_{dk} $. Where I minimize the fixed cost of opening the OR  and $\sigma_{dk}$.

The cut I have is exactly the way you described by equation 1. I still do not understand what you mean by subset/superset of support of x. Can you please help with little details so that I can include cuts given by equation 2 and 3 in correct manner?

Comment: Constraint (1) applies when the conditional is $x=x^*$, that is $\land_j (x_j = x_j^*)$.  Constraint (2) applies when the conditional is $\land_j (x_j \le x_j^*)$.  Constraint (3) applies when the conditional is $\land_j (x_j \ge x_j^*)$.

Comment: Can you please provide me reference to above cuts that you have mentioned? I would like to learn more about it?

Comment: I don't have my copy in front of me, but I believe both (2) and (3) are mentioned in the "50 Years of Integer Programming" book you referenced.

Comment: Please provide me reference if you can find it. I did not find the above cuts in the book but as you say, I am sure that they must have been mentioned in the book.

A question about the cuts, here in (2) and (3), the $x_j^*$ mentioned are all the variables in master problem is that correct? For example, I have $X_{idk}$ as MP variable. When I solve subproblem for (d,k), value for $X_{idk} = 0$ for all $i \notin N_{dk}$, so the cut (2) will not be valid cut if the cut is written for $i \in N_{dk}$ instead of $i \in N$. Can you confirm this? Is this also true for cut (3)

Comment: Page 469 mentions the feasibility cut version of (2), but it is the same idea.  Yes, $x^*_j$ are the master variables.  When you generate the cuts for subproblem $(d,k)$, only the variables $X_{idk}$ that affect that subproblem should appear.  If you instead use all master variables, the resulting cut is valid but weaker.

Comment: Great answer Rob. I used all the information above but it turns out that even after a long time, the benders algorithm does not converge. Is there anything else I can do to the problem that might help? Further, would these cuts be valid for other ORs for exact same surgery assignment? I suspect that symmetry of the problem is also an issue here.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full formulation of the original problem.

Comment: It seems that cuts 3 do not work the way it is intended, 
E.g. No of Surgeries = 7, Days = 3, the problem is simplified to the daily rather than for (day, OR). Suppose the daily assignment is 1: {1,2,3} costs 100,2:{4, 5,6}  costs 110,  3:{7} costs 120.

Cut for day 2,
$$\theta_{2} \geq 1100 - (1100 -L_2)*(3-X_{4,2} -X_{5,2} -X_{6,2}) $$ 

Suppose that surgery 7 is added to day 2. The RHS term of X's is 0 and thus cut is tight. If adding surgery 7 to day 2 increases the cost to 1500, then cut added,
$$\theta_{2} \geq 1500 - (1500 -L_{2.1})*(4-X_{4,2} -X_{5,2} -X_{6,2}-X_{7,2})$$

Comment: Continued, If this solution is repeated, we have 2 constraints, $\theta_{2} \geq 1500$ and $\theta_{2} \geq 1100$.

However, if adding the surgery 7 to day2 reduces the cost of day, since now you don't incur idle time cost in day 2, then cut added at this iteration will be,

$$\theta_{2} \geq 800 - (800 -L_{2.2})*(4-X_{4,2} -X_{5,2} -X_{6,2}-X_{7,2})$$
If this solution repeats, we have 2 constraints, $\theta_{2} \geq 800$ and $\theta_{2} \geq 1100$.
Ideally, you only want the above constraint, isn't that correct? How do you handle the fact that cost can be reduced by adding surgery?

Comment: Correction, No of Surgeries = 7, Days = 3, the problem is simplified to the daily rather than for (day, OR). Suppose the daily assignment is 1: {1,2,3} costs 1000,2:{4, 5,6} costs 1100, 3:{7} costs 1200.

Comment: Your example shows that the conditions for using (3) are not met.  In particular, $(X_{4,2} \land X_{5,2} \land X_{6,2}) \implies \theta_2 \ge 1100$ is not valid. You need to use (1) instead.

Comment: I see. So does that mean that I need to know the solution to every superset of X4, X5, X6 to be able to add 3? Suppose every superset yields the cost >1100 only then I can use 3?  Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need to know the solution to every superset.  You just need to know that every superset costs at least as much.

Comment: Can you help me prove this result? I could use a starting point why cut 2 and 3 work.

Comment: For (2), consider two cases: $\sum_{j:x_j^*=0} x_j = 0$ and $\sum_{j:x_j^*=0} x_j \ge 1$.  The first case corresponds to the support of $x$ being a subset of the support of $x^*$, and (2) reduces to the assumed inequality.  The second case corresponds to the support of $x$ *not* being a subset of the support of $x^*$, and (2) is redundant by the choice of big-M.  So (2) is valid in both possible cases.